# How to send multiple files with JSON data from NodeJs to React

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, node.js

How do I send multiple files alongside with JSON data from Node.js to React? I am adding a use case which has `Name`, `Description`, `Actors`, `Pre-Conditions`, `Post-Conditions`, `Steps`, `Test Cases` and `Picture` attributes/fields/properties. How do I add the `picture`? (Picture is in form data and others are in JSON form.)

[image: Form for adding a usecase]

[image: Form for post conditions, picture, etc.]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't you mean React to Node? You want to sent JSON data along with Images from client to server right?

Comment: i want to send data like name, description, etc in json form and picture in form data soo how i can send multiple things.

Comment: code: axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/usecases", usecaseData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Usecase added successfully:", response.data);
        setUsecase({
          name: "",
          description: "",
          objectives: "",
          actors: "",
          preConditions: "",
          postConditions: "",
          steps: [],
          testCases: [],
          picture: null,
          assignedDomainObjects: [],
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error adding Usecase:", error);
      });
  };

Comment: const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    setUsecase({
      ...usecase,
      picture: e.target.files[0],
    });
  };

Comment: <div>
        <label>Picture:</label>
        <input type="file" name="picture" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      </div>